How do I align this cart so that it always runs on the curves created in edit mode?
I want this cart to follow the track continuously, but during playback I keep seeing gaps between the wheels and the rails:

I find these gaps in bends. I want it to stay on the track even in bends.
This is the setup used to create the track:

These nodes are for the animation and instancing:

Any suggestions how to fix this?



This answer is not much different from Markus's answer, and just shows how you would need to use it in your case.

You did almost everything right.
However, you should note two things here:

The cart must be aligned along two axes (normals and tangents) along the curve
You would have to query the normal and tangent of the curve at a specific factor/length using Sample Curve.

The node Trim Curve may sound tempting in this case, but the values are interpolated in such a way that they are only of limited use for this use case.
It's more or less like this:

And of course, you can also use the Axes to Rotation node directly instead of chaining two Align Rotation to Vector nodes:


This works perfectly thank you.
Does trim curve strip off some information ? Because i was struggling to find normal information after trim curve before i posted here, tried to capture normal after but it wasn't working then.

@samar You are welcome! Basically, Trim Curve does not modify any information from existing points, except for the end points. These are recalculated when trimming and then no longer correspond to the interpolated values between two points that you can obtain with Sample Curves.

The easiest solution is to calculate the position of tracks based on a single curve to then use same calculation for contact points of wheels. Then it's a matter of aligning the axle (pair of wheels):

I disconnected aligning Z to to tangent - I'm not sure if it should be aligned. After all, the rotation is already done based on distance traveled, and for thin tracks it shouldn't matter in what direction the cart rotates.
The axle angle calculation could be simplified, as radians(-360) $= 2π$, so it cancels out with the other 2π and all you need is to divide length by radius and multiply by $-1$ to rotate in the right direction.



why it works
Imagine that instead of using two circles,  you would use four like so:
8    8

This way there's no possibility for misalignment between top and bottom circles.  The way I approach this is by:

using a symmetrical double circle profile - this way each circle is the same distance and at the same (reflected) angle in relation to the "path" - the input curve.
the axle has to be symmetrical too. This way the center of the axle is the origin,  and so it can be easily aligned to any point sampled on the "path".
the distance between wheel contact points to origin is the same as the distance of profile circle centers to profile origin.  This ensures the 2 have to match if the angle is right.
the angle is right because both the profile and the axle are axis- aligned, so it's just a matter of matching the axes and aligning them to the same thing which is curve tangent and normal. I actually should resign from the cross product and just align the axle axis to the normal.


Thanks for the response. I'm curious why those particular values on map range '0-100', '6-8' and also why the Mix vector factor is .700.

@samar all those are arbitrary: I animated it on frames 0-100, figured an angle for presentation is good between 6th and 8th meters, and I reduced the twist of the curve so that there is some but not as big as on an unchanged spiral.

Ok. Well this hasn't solved it. The bends on my curve are lesser than a spiral. Its basically an S shaped bend. It goes off center after 100 frames. I have followed the steps as per your node tree. Im probably making an error i cant yet see

@samar if the narrow bending is the problem then it's not an alignment problem. But this is not what we can see on your screenshot with the cart being on a straight segment.  I'll modify my answer to explicitly explain the principles of my setup that make it work

In the first 20 frames, the cart is making a somersault. then it aligns correctly but then at the first slight bend it misaligns again.

As for your explanation. If you opened my blend file, you'd find im already making 4 circles. Your solution is regarding two wheels on one axle, my cart has 4 wheels and two axles. Probably why im having a discrepancy in alignment  at bends.

@samar you can't align entire cart, you can only align axles. You need suspension between axles and a car if the axles can have different orientations (and they usually can). But averaging the two axles - or just treating the car as one axle - shouldn't produce the problems you're describing (and that's not how your screenshot at the question looks)

Nevermind opening the blend file and seeing it for yourself. Defeats the entire purpose of me uploading it. Besides the screenshot pretty clearly shows the curve tilt of the parallel track and the car having different orientation (not a difference between front and back wheels, but as a whole tilted sideways). please remove your solution as i cant even downvote it. Long story short, it doesnt work.

@samar the .blend file is only complementary to the question. It is helpful to not reproduce the setup to write an answer, but the question shouldn't rely on the .blend file explaining the issue.

There is an alignment issue in the screengrab. If you did not see that and produced an answer then its not with knowing the facts of the case. I have uploaded questions here before and always been asked for a blend file. anyways thank you so much but this does not work

@samar have you tried passing your curve as the "path" to my setup?

Yes. I placed my curve in place of the spiral in your example. Only difference is that my curve is coming from group input geometry as it's made outside GeoNodes in edit mode.
